# How do I check for the length of a context variable in a java component?

Tags: java, talend

I've tried:

```
if(StringHandling.LEN(context.last_record_filter_value) == 0)
```

But this ALWAYS evaluates true regardless of the length of the string.  When I attempt to put the zero in quotes, it doesn't like it since it is comparing an integer to a string.  I am going to set a context variable to 0 and compare it to that for now but there must be a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Comment: What is `StringHandling.LEN`, where is it defined, what's its implementation? What type is `context.last_record_filter_value`?

Answer (score 0):

If your context variable is defined as a string data type, simply use the `length()` function to compare ...

```
if(context.last_record_filter_value.length() == 0)
```

... or the `isEmpty()` method ...

```
if(context.last_record_filter_value.isEmpty())
```

It should be noted that `isEmpty()` will not work if the string is `null`, for obvious reasons, i.e. it’ll throw an exception if you try to call a method on a null variable. In that case, use `== null`.